# Laravel: Error 404 after clicking redirecting button in view

Tags: php, laravel

When i try to make duplicate records from one wiev and table to another view and table using button in view, Laravel shows me error 404. This button redirect to route and route redirect to controller but I don't know where is the bug. I don'tknow what to do with this. Cen anybody help me?

This is part of view with redirecting button.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form action="{{ route('proforms.duplicate') }}" method="POST">
@csrf

<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" value="1" name="duplicate" class="form-control" readonly>
<span class="input-group-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wystaw fakturę</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

This is route for it:

```
Route::post('/duplicate', 'ProformController@duplicate')->name('proforms.duplicate');
```

This is controller method for it:

```
public function duplicate(Request $request)
{
 

$autoyear = date('Y');
$automonth = date('m');

$autonumber = DB::table('proforms')
            ->select(DB::raw('MAX(autonumber) as autonumber'))
            ->where('automonth', '=', '$automonth')
            ->where('autoyear', '=', '$autoyear')
            ->get();
@$auto = @$autonumber[0]->autonumber;
@$auto[0]++;


$user = User::all('showname','id');
$proform = $this->proform->findOrFail($request->duplicate);
$proforms = Proform::sortable()->paginate(5);
/*
//something like this
$duplicated = Invoice::create([
'invoicenumber' => $proform->proformnumber,
'invoicedate' => $proform->proformdate,
'selldate' => $proform->selldate,
'user_id' => $proform->user_id,
'form_id' => $proform->form_id,
'currency_id' => $proform->currency_id,
'paymentmethod' => $proform->paymentmethod,
'paymentdate' => $proform->paymentdate,
'status' => $proform->status,
'comments' => $proform->comments,
'city' => $proform->city,
'autonumber' => $proform->autonumber,
'automonth' => $proform->automonth,
'autoyear' => $proform->autoyear,
'name' => $proform->name,
'PKWIU' => $proform->PKWIU,
'quantity' => $proform->quantity,
'unit' => $proform->unit,
'netunit' => $proform->netunit,
'nettotal' => $proform->nettotal,
'VATrate' => $proform->VATrate,
'grossunit' => $proform->grossunit,
'grosstotal' => $proform->grosstotal,

]); */

DB::table('invoices')->insert([
['invoicenumber' => $proform->proformnumber,
'invoicedate' => $proform->proformdate,
'selldate' => $proform->selldate,
'user_id' => $proform->user_id,
'form_id' => $proform->form_id,
'currency_id' => $proform->currency_id,
'paymentmethod' => $proform->paymentmethod,
'paymentdate' => $proform->paymentdate,
'status' => $proform->status,
'comments' => $proform->comments,
'city' => $proform->city,
'autonumber' => $proform->autonumber,
'automonth' => $proform->automonth,
'autoyear' => $proform->autoyear,
'name' => $proform->name,
'PKWIU' => $proform->PKWIU,
'quantity' => $proform->quantity,
'unit' => $proform->unit,
'netunit' => $proform->netunit,
'nettotal' => $proform->nettotal,
'VATrate' => $proform->VATrate,
'grossunit' => $proform->grossunit,
'grosstotal' => $proform->grosstotal,
'autonumber' => $number, 
'automonth' => $automonth, 
'autoyear'=> $autoyear],

]);
return view('proforms.show',compact('proform', 'user'))
->with('sukces','Faktura wystawiona');
}
```

Comment: your bug is on this line `$proform = $this->proform->findOrFail($request->duplicate);`

Comment: What is `$this->proform`? if I assume it is the **Proform** Model, then your `findOrFail(1)` is looking for the id 1 in your DB, can't find it and returns a 404

Answer (score 0):

The `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);

$model = App\Flight::where('legs', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
```

So if that id doesn't exist in the database. **ModelNotFoundException will give you a 404 error**.

If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user. It is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using these methods:

```
Route::get('/api/flights/{id}', function ($id) {
    return App\Flight::findOrFail($id);
});
```